# Positioning two blocks in absolute position for desktop and relative position for mobile using CSS or Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to perform the below task as shown in the image. I tried with css coding and failed to this. Is it possible with CSS, if not how to achieve this task with jquery.

**For desktop :** 
I am trying Block 1 and block 2 are in absolute position to container, while block 2 position relative to block 1 with height auto. Block 3 position relative to container.

**For Mobile**
In the mobile view I want only block 1 in the absolute bottom position of the container and block 2 and block 3 position relative to container as shown in the picture.

[image: I want to perform this task using CSS]

```
<style>
.container{
    width:100%;
    min-height:768px;
    height:auto;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    background:#666;
}
.b-50{
    width:50%;
}
.pinned1{
    background:#888;
    float:right;
    display:block;
    padding:20px;
    height:auto;
    color:#FFF;
}
.pinned2{
    background:#888;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    float:right;
    color:#FFF;
    padding:20px;
    height:auto;
}
.block3{
    display:block;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:auto;
    top:100%;
}
@media all and (max-width: 767px){
.b-50{
    width:100%;
}
.pinned2{
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
}

}
</style>
<div class="container">
          <div class="b-50 pinned1">
              <h1>Block 1</h1>
          </div>    
          <div class="b-50 pinned2">
              <h2>Block 2</h2>
          </div>
</div>
<div class="block3">
    <h3>Block 3</h3>
</div>
```

[Demo JSFIDDLDE](http://jsfiddle.net/LSB3a/)

Comment: do not do this using CSS, you need to move beyond the container block 2 using JS

Comment: I didn't tried to solve this using jquery. Any idea about this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a pure CSS solution is a tough problem because you want to make it appear as if the nesting of elements has changed!

It can be accomplished by relying on the fact that floating elements dont affect their parents height unless there is a clear:both element below them (the  [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html) ). We then make the parent ignore the height of the second child on the mobile site.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="box1"> </div>    

   <div class="clear-mobile"></div>

   <div class="box2"> </div>    

   <div class="clear-desktop></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
/* for desktop */
.clear-desktop{
    clear: both;   
}

@(max-width: 767px)

  .box2{
    margin-top: 40px;
  }
  .clear-mobile{
    clear: both;
  }
  .clear-desktop{
    clear: none;   /* now container will ignore .box2's height! */
  }
}
```

posible with css only!

http://jsfiddle.net/b5Kyy/2/

Comment: Right. It always depends on how complex the "nesting" look actually is. So without the real design it might be hard to guess. If you really have something like the red background it is harder than with just positioning on white background

Comment: np, that was a fun exersize

Answer (score 2):

depends on how you want to define mobile/desktop browsers. There are actually 2 different approaches:

1. responsive. The difference is checked by the dimensions of your browser. You can use media-queries in CSS for that. Advantage: if someone uses a really small desktop browser, it will have the same effect there. THis is usually what you want when you change position of elements
2. functionality. if your change in position is done because of functionality (e.g. touch/swipe movements instead of click) then you should use JS to check for the browser version. jQuery for example provides code for that.

I think what you need is Version 1.

Comment: I am trying for the responsive approach but I am confused how to solve this problem using CSS.

Comment: I'll see what I can do for you

Comment: How to handle this problem. Taking (Block 2)<div> inside the container or outside.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/2mDxa/2/

Adjusted the html:

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="b-50 pinned1">
          <h1>Block 1</h1>
      </div>     
</div>
<div class="b-50 pinned2">
  <h2>Block 2</h2>
</div>
<div class="block3">
    <h3>Block 3</h3>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
}
.container{
    width:100%;
    min-height:768px;
    height:auto;
    margin:0 0 20px 0;
    padding:0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display:block;
    background:#666;
    position: relative;
}
.b-50{
    width:50%;
}
.pinned1{
    background:red;
    float:right;
    display:block;
    padding:20px;
    height:auto;
    color:#FFF;
}
.pinned2{
    background:green;
    display:block;
    right: 0;
    top: 120px;  
    position: absolute; 
    color:#FFF;
    padding:20px;
    height:auto;
}

.block3{
    background:blue;
    position:relative;
    display:block; 
    color:#FFF;
    padding:20px;
    height:auto;
}
.block3{
    display:block;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:auto;
    top:100%;
}
@media all and (max-width: 767px){
    .b-50{
        width:100%;
    }
    .pinned1{
        position:absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
    }
    .pinned2{
        position: relative;
        right: auto;
        top: auto;
        margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Mat this is the exact which I was looking for.

Comment: No problems, glad to of helped. I think there are many ways to tackle this, and this is just my take on a possible solution :)

Comment: this works but will break if .pinned1 needs to resize or elements are added before .container

Comment: Yeh it's not perfect, although you could probably neaten it up more so it's more robust, although I'm someone who needs to see the whole picture to properly get my head around something. I hope it does prove useful as a starting point